# HTML row overlapping onto next?

Tags: html, css

When one of my rows is wider than the table it is going onto the next line, but the next row is also being displayed there. What setting/property can i change in CSS to ensure multiple rows arent being displayed on the same line, when they are wider than the table?

Comment: It's hard to visualise what you're describing without some markup (HTML and CSS) to see, post that in and we'll be able to help you more. A live example can't hurt either.

Comment: I think the true question (apart why are you using table layout) is why some rows are wider than the table.

Comment: Because i am displaying data which is user-entered describing universities and there are various lengths of university names.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing any example HTML / CSS, try setting `overflow: hidden;` on your affected table rows.